# I installed Jekyll, but it looks weird when I try to run it. What's wrong?

Tags: web, installation, jekyll

I followed the guide on the Jekyll website. This is what I get when I go to the my website address:

[image]

I click on _site and get this:

[image]

I do not know what is wrong. :-(

Comment: its likely the css somehow, although its hard to say with the information provided what the exact nature of the issue is

Comment: Nothing is wrong. That is what you get when you start a new site in some setups. You will have to write the CSS and the contents. I guess you may want to install SASS, if it is not installed yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are looking at the generated files without a web server, fortunately Jekyll comes with one for testing your site locally, just run this at the root folder of your jekyll instance (i.e. the folder that contains `_config.yml`:

```
$ jekyll serve
```

or if you are using bundler:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Then you will be able to access your website at: http://localhost:4000

Answer (score 0):

Because of the limited information in the question, its hard to provide an answer.
The page you're opening in the first screenshot is the `source` directory. This means that you did not follow the guide properly as its not accessible via browser normally.

But don't loose heart, the following steps should hopefully get you up and running:

(the example assumes your site is located at `my_blog` and has default configuration.)

Step 1: Get Ready.
You need Bundler for this example. So install it by running:

```
$ gem install bundler
```

Step 2: Check Gemfile
Your Gemfile should contain the following:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll", "~> 3.4"
gem "minima", "~> 2.0"

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.8"
end
```

Step 3: Run Jekyll server

```
# move into project directory (my_blog):
cd my_blog

# start Jekyll server with Bundler
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Step 4: Preview in browser

- Open Browser
- Go to `http://localhost:4000`